# Field not found exception

Tags: column, exception

I have an ASP.NET Web Service (ASMX) and a class for working with lists (CRUD operations).
Web service's method calls method (retrieve item from list) from CRUD-operations class and then I recieve an exception

> "The field is not found. May be it was changed or deleted by another
>   user."

Why it happens?

The field do exists in list.

Comment: As the exception says, it cannot find one of the fields you are trying to access from a List. Make sure all the fields exist and their internal names are being used.

Comment: Field really exists in list.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or share your code to check what are trying to do in service call?

Comment: I do not understand why, but when I re-deploy all lists completely, not just the one in which was an error, then it worked. Thanks for replies ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to list setting page and click on the field name. In the url check for query string "Field" the value after = sign is the name of column.

```
/_layouts/FldEditEx.aspx?List=%7BA247F2E0%2D3B53%2D4CDF%2D8FFB%2D62E1C3F042DB%7D&**Field=Author**
```

Answer (score 0):

please post the field your trying to call from the webservice. 9 times out of 10 the code is correct but the field is wrong! by wrong i mean:

If for example i have the field 'My ID' and i want to call it or query it, usually people search using 'My ID' which is the display version. Try using the internal name instead which if it does contain a space would be: 'My_x0020_ID'

also how long is the field? as there is also a strict ammount you can go upto which i think is a max of 32 characters. for a list of default internal names if your trying to reference them than refer to this list:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx

sorry to big to list here, within the list you can see the display name and the internal name... when referencing to the field use the internal or id if known.

also like to note without code we are only presuming here that the code is correct and you need to reference using internal not display name of a field ;)